# pandas.DataFrame.apply() failing after pandas.to_datetime()

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

The following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a'], 'col2': ['b'], 'col3': ['15/12/2001']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['col1'] = df1.col1
df2['col2'] = df1.col2
df2['col3'] = df1.col3

def convert(r):
    return 'a', 'b'

df2.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

outputs
    0    (a, b)
    dtype: object

In contrast, the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a'], 'col2': ['b'], 'col3': ['15/12/2001']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['col1'] = df1.col1
df2['col2'] = df1.col2
df2['col3'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['col3'], dayfirst=True)

def convert(r):
    return 'a', 'b'

df2.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

raises an error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   3928         blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
-> 3929         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   3930         mgr._consolidate_inplace()

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check, fastpath)
   2536         if do_integrity_check:
-> 2537             self._verify_integrity()
   2538 

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _verify_integrity(self)
   2746             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
-> 2747                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
   2748         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   3898     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 3899         passed, implied))
   3900 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 3)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-e8fcbf9d6e00> in <module>()
     12     return 'a', 'b'
     13 
---> 14 df2.apply(convert, axis=1)

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4040                     if reduce is None:
   4041                         reduce = True
-> 4042                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4043             else:
   4044                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4153                 index = None
   4154 
-> 4155             result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
   4156             result.columns = res_index
   4157 

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    221                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    222         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 223             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    224         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    225             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    357             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    358 
--> 359         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    360 
    361     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5248     axes = [_ensure_index(columns), _ensure_index(index)]
   5249 
-> 5250     return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
   5251 
   5252 

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   3931         return mgr
   3932     except ValueError as e:
-> 3933         construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
   3934 
   3935 

/home/michel/.virtualenvs/stsisi/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   3897         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   3898     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 3899         passed, implied))
   3900 
   3901 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 3)
```

It looks to me like a bug involving pandas.to_datetime() and pandas.DataFrame.apply(). Am I missing something ?

I ran it with python 3.4.3 and pandas 0.18.0

Comment: Works for me on python 3.4 and pandas 0.17.1 what versions are you running

Comment: it looks like a new feature from pandas 0.18.0 - i have the same error message with pandas 0.18.0

Comment: And actually it's fair enough...

Comment: I get same error message with pandas 0.16.1 and python 2.  I don't know if it's a bug or not, but I don't know why you would want to do what you are trying to do.  I mean, in the version above that works, what are you actually trying to do?  I think this is a case where a slightly more realistic version of your problem might help.