# Python: 2 Columns containing lists. How to get a new column that removes any common values between those 2 lists?

Tags: python, list, date, pandas, apply

I have the following DataFrame:

```
  carrier  flightnumber departureAirport arrivalAirport effectiveDate                                               date                                        group_dates
0      4U          9748              DUS            GVA    2017-05-09  [2017-05-09, 2017-05-10, 2017-05-11, 2017-05-1...  [2017-05-09, 2017-05-10, 2017-05-11, 2017-05-1...
1      4U          9748              DUS            GVA    2017-05-14  [2017-05-14, 2017-05-15, 2017-05-16, 2017-05-1...  [2017-05-09, 2017-05-10, 2017-05-11, 2017-05-1...
2      4U          9748              DUS            GVA    2017-07-08  [2017-07-08, 2017-07-09, 2017-07-10, 2017-07-1...  [2017-05-09, 2017-05-10, 2017-05-11, 2017-05-1...
3      AG          1234              SFO            DFW    2017-03-09  [2017-03-09, 2017-03-10, 2017-03-11, 2017-03-1...  [2017-03-09, 2017-03-10, 2017-03-11, 2017-03-1...
4      AG          1234              SFO            DFW    2017-03-14  [2017-03-14, 2017-03-15, 2017-03-16, 2017-03-1...  [2017-03-09, 2017-03-10, 2017-03-11, 2017-03-1...
```

I want to create a new column that is basically the same as the column `group_dates` but removing any element listed in the column `date`

Here's what I've done:

I created a custom function and passed it to `apply`

```
def get_unique_dates(row):
    return [x for x in row['group_dates'] if x not in row['date']]

df['unique_dates'] = df.apply(get_unique_dates, axis=1)
```

But this is returning the following error:

```
ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.
```

Comment: Which version is your pandas?

Comment: I am using version 0.20.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slow (`.apply(..., axis=1)`) approach:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
              a          b
0  [a, b, c, d]     [e, a]
1     [x, y, z]  [g, i, z]

In [26]: df['a_b'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x.a) - set(x.b)), axis=1)

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
              a          b        a_b
0  [a, b, c, d]     [e, a]  [c, d, b]
1     [x, y, z]  [g, i, z]     [y, x]
```

Comment: It seems as though I am still getting the same error: ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `numpy.setdiff1d`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['x', 'y', 'z']],'GroupDate':[['e', 'a'],['g', 'i', 'z']]})
df['setdiff']=df.apply(lambda x: list(np.setdiff1d(x.GroupDate, x.Date)), axis=1)
df
Out[26]: 
           Date  GroupDate setdiff
0  [a, b, c, d]     [e, a]     [e]
1     [x, y, z]  [g, i, z]  [g, i]
```

Comment: Getting error message: ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.

Comment: @RileyHun I am working on Python 3.6 ,it is works well on my side.  What is your python version ? Also, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992420/pandas-dataframe-apply-failing-after-pandas-to-datetime

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5